# Looking for the title of a folklore which was about moon princess being jealous of her sister sun princess

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, folk-tales

I read this short story back in middle school during my literature class when we were studying about folklore. It was about a moon princess being jealous of her sister sun princess so much that she adorned herself in jewels enough to make the night disappear just so she can shine like her sister. People became lost and everything went terrible and the moon became so sad cause all she wanted was the people's attention. He mother advised her to try wearing ash to make her moonlight soft that will help people. I think it was something like this. I just can't remember the title of the short story.